# when i give drive link as media url it is not working, but amazon s3 works fine?

Tags: google-drive-api, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am a student and trying to build some apps for the google assistant where I built apps using the templates.

But now I wanted to build something with dialogflow and the app is about playing audio like ok google, play relaxing sounds and I have even built that but when it comes to give media URL I have stored my files on the google drive and as well as amzons3 where the amazon link works perfectly fine but the google drive link is not working. It just says loading and just keeps like loading ?

Can anyone help me resolve the issue please .

drive audio link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SIpcTAJy7Kr-AyP6H_dSbPU95zh5gGl_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide code you have wrote.

Comment: Please update your question to include the code and sample URLs that aren't working.

Comment: i have not written any code , in dailougeflow we have a option to add media response i made use of it

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive works for sharing an embedded version of an audio file, although it is not designed to act as a direct-link storage system. If you want to use a file-hosting server, you may want to use a service like [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/), which works great in conjunction with Firebase Functions for fulfillment. Alternatively, you can stick with using Amazon's hosting for the same files.

Comment: I'll just add that otherwise you can use Google Storage, associated with your project. This also provides a web-link to play your audio.

Comment: yes i tried but it won't work ...i used firebse storage ?

Comment: What exactly did you try?